# How do I get a custom minecraft map into my own save file without deleting anything in the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know because i want to keep my world and have a cool custom downloaded  build inside that world without having to actually build it.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to move that custom map into the saves in **.minecraft** to make a separate map, you can use the MCEdit feature called schematics. You can load a world, make a selection and choose to export as schematic (Will have the icon of a crane on the navbar). You can then load your world, import the schematic, and drag & drop the selection to your world.

Be sure to save, as I always tend to forget ;)

Answer (score -1):

his might help if you're new to MCEdit